# stopPropagation prevents ajax success callback function from being called

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I have a button inside a div

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <button data-details-rid="@Model.RequestId">Details</button>
</div>
```

and a jquery functions which run on-click event:

```
$("[data-details-rid]").on('click', function (event) {
    var request_id = $(this).attr('data-details-rid');
    console.log(request_id);
    var request_details = {};
    request_details.url = "/Requests/Details?RequestId=" + request_id;
    request_details.async = false;
    request_details.datatype = "html";
    request_details.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request_details.success = function (request_info) {/*...*/};
    $.ajax(request_details);
});

$("#outerDiv").on('click', function (event) {
    another ajax call
});
```

now, obviously, when I click the button the the `#outerDiv` function is called too (undesirable affect).

when I put `event.stopPropagation()` like this:

```
$("[data-details-rid]").on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var request_id = $(this).attr('data-details-rid');
    console.log(request_id);
    var request_details = {};
    request_details.url = "/Requests/Details?RequestId=" + request_id;
    request_details.async = false;
    request_details.datatype = "html";
    request_details.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request_details.success = function (request_info) {/*...*/};
    $.ajax(request_details);
});
```

then the ajax success function is not executed. 
why?

Comment: Check your console please for errors when you click the button with `[data-details-rid]`. Meanwhile, the object you are passing should have `dataType` and NOT `datatype`.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri I checked the console. no error message or any other message. The jQuery function is called, the success callback doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: What if you remove the `preventDefault` method and `return false` in the end of the function.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri I don't know exactly what is the 'preventDefault' method. However, I put 'return false' at the end of the function and again, the success function has not being called.

Comment: What is printed on your console when you click the button now after returning false. (If you had firebug (for Firefox), debugging would have been much easier.)

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri I see. You are very right. Actually the success function IS BEING CALLED and everything works just fine. However, a bootstrap's modal dialog does not appear. I guess I should rewrite the whole question. Maybe put another one.

Comment: Forgot to mention totally, DO specify a `type="button"` on that button that you have, in case it's inside a `form` element, it will trigger form submission and ajax will never get called.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri no, it's not inside a form. good point.

Comment: Ok, waiting for the edit.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri I put another question because editing will make the whole conversation unclear to readers. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296638/stoppropagation-prevents-bootstraps-dialog-to-be-shown