# stopPropagation prevents bootstrap's dialog to be shown

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, stoppropagation

I have a button inside a div

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <button data-details-rid="@Model.RequestId" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showRequestModal">Details</button>
</div>
```

A `bootstrap`'s modal dialog

```
   <div id="showRequestModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <div id="request-details-title">Details</div>
                </div>
                <div id="request-details-modal-body" class="modal-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and a jquery functions which run on-click event:

```
    $("[data-details-rid]").on('click', function (event) {
        var request_id = $(this).attr('data-details-rid');
        console.log(request_id);
        var request_details = {};
        request_details.url = "/Requests/Details?RequestId=" + request_id;
        request_details.async = false;
        request_details.datatype = "html";
        request_details.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request_details.success = function (request_info) {/*...*/};
        $.ajax(request_details);
    });

$("#outerDiv").on('click', function (event) {
    another ajax call
});
```

now, obviously, when I click the button the the `#outerDiv` function is called too (undesirable affect).

when I put `event.stopPropagation()` like this:

```
$("[data-details-rid]").on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var request_id = $(this).attr('data-details-rid');
    console.log(request_id);
    var request_details = {};
    request_details.url = "/Requests/Details?RequestId=" + request_id;
    request_details.async = false;
    request_details.datatype = "html";
    request_details.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request_details.success = function (request_info) {/*...*/};
    $.ajax(request_details);
});
```

then the modal dialogue does not appear. 
why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. By using `stopPropagation` you are basically saying that no more click event handlers will be notified of that event like you can read in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). You can however trigger the modal manually using:
`$("#showRequestModal").modal('show');`

Comment: You probably meant:             $("#showRequestModal").modal('show'); Wonderful! it works. Thank you.