# Unable to open a pop up using $("#popup").modal("show");

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to open a pop up using node js but i am unable to open.
I have checked that data is coming from backend and is passing to front end but still pop up is not opening.

I have attached screenshot also.
Appreciate help on this. I am fed up with this since 2 months.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LH0g.png)
Below is my code.

```
  <!-- Modal Popup For Customer Detail & Their Related data -->
        <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="popup">

            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title"> Customer Details</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
                   label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <nav>
                                    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" 
                 role="tablist">
                                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" 
         data-toggle="tab"
                                            href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav- 
           home"
                                            aria-selected="true">Details</a>
                                 <!--
                              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data- 
                              toggle="tab"
                                            href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile"
                                            aria-selected="false">Related</a> 
                                 -->       
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" 
                                   role="tabpanel"
                                        aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">

                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table id="activityCodeDetail" class="table table- 
                                            hover striped">
                                                <!-- Inside code is handled by Jquery to add 
                                   dyanamic Content -->
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
              dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></body>
        <script>
          function anchorClickFunctionalities() {
                $('a.ActivityTag').on('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    vendorIDS = this.id;
                    let vendorId = this.id;
                    console.log('vendor id ++ '+vendorId);
                    //  alert('vendorTag=>'+vendorId);
                    $("#popup").modal("show");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/approvals/individualcustomerdetails',
                        data: {
                            'customerId': vendorId
                        },
                        dataType: 'json'
                    })
                        .done((data) => {
                            let recordData = data[0];
                            console.log('DATA DEtails=>' + JSON.stringify(data.customerDetails));
                            let record = data.customerDetails;
                            console.log('DATA record=>' + JSON.stringify(record));
                            if (data.customerDetails.length > 0) {
                                console.log('Inside ActivityCode Details');
                                let ActivityCodeDetailRow = '';
                                data.ActivityCodeDetail.forEach((eachRecord) => {
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<tr>';
                                    //ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td colspan="4" style="background-color:#d3d3d3;"><h5>Activity Code Metrics</h5></td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '</tr>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<tr>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td><strong> Name<span style="color: red;">*</span><strong></td>';
             ]                       ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td>' + eachRecord.name + '</td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td><strong>Mobile<strong></td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td>' + eachRecord.mob + '</td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '</tr>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<tr>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td><strong>Address<strong></td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td>' + eachRecord.address + '</td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td><strong> GST No<strong></td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<td>' + eachRecord.gstno + '</td>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '</tr>';
                                    ActivityCodeDetailRow += '<tr>';
                                  $('#activityCodeDetail').html(ActivityCodeDetailRow);
                                })
                            }
           
                        })
                        .fail((jqXHR, textStatus, err) => {
                            console.log('textStatus  : ' + textStatus);
                        })
                })
            }
```

I am passing data from node js file to ejs and then trying to redirect to pop up. Stop immediate propagation is working also on click is also working but still pop up is not opening

Answer (score 0):

Removing event.stopImmediatePropagation(); and event.stopPropagation(); should solve your problem.

[stopPropagation prevents bootstrap's dialog to be shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296638/stoppropagation-prevents-bootstraps-dialog-to-be-shown)